# adding to an array with each recursive function

Tags: php, arrays, function

I want to add to an array when each recursive function is called. I have played around with it a few ways, but just getting error after error. This is about where I am up to, it should be enough to work out what I am trying to accomplish.

```
function structure($x, $structure = array()) {
$qry = mysql_query("SELECT `parent_id` FROM `categories` WHERE `categories_id`=$x");
$result = mysql_fetch_assoc($qry);
$cat = $result['parent_id'];
if($cat !=0) {
    structure($cat, $structure[] = $cat);
}
echo $cat.' >';
return $structure;
}

echo structure(22);
var_dump($structure);
```

So I am also trying to return the array as well, unsuccessfully. I am not sure how you return an array from a function either.

So I would appreciate help on how to add to an array with each recursive function and return the array outside of the function into a useable variable.

Comment: What about `$structure = structure(22);` ?

Comment: oh, is that how I can return the array then? I can't test it until I can create the array in the first place though.

Answer (score 0):

```
if($cat !=0) {
    $structure = structure($cat, $structure[] = $cat);
}
```

as structure() return a value, you need to set it to a variable, so this variable is fed on every call.
And at the end :

```
$whatever = structure(22);
var_dump($whatever );
```